# Use an ufunc analogous to numpy.where

Tags: numpy

For example, if I want to add conditionally, I can use:

```
y = numpy.where(condition, a+b, b)
```

Is there a way to directly combine an `ufunc` and `where`? Something like:

```
y = numpy.add.where(condition, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along that line is `add.at`.

```
In [21]: b = np.arange(10)
In [22]: cond = b%3==0
```

Your `where`:

```
In [24]: np.where(cond, 10+b, b)
Out[24]: array([10,  1,  2, 13,  4,  5, 16,  7,  8, 19])
```

Use the other `where` (or `np.nonzeros`) to turn the boolean mask into index tuple

```
In [25]: cond
Out[25]: array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [26]: idx = np.where(cond)
In [27]: idx
Out[27]: (array([0, 3, 6, 9], dtype=int32),)
```

`add.at` does inplace, unbuffered addition:

```
In [28]: np.add.at(b,idx[0],10)
In [29]: b
Out[29]: array([10,  1,  2, 13,  4,  5, 16,  7,  8, 19])
```

`add.at` is intended as a way of getting around buffering problems with the more direct index `+=`:

```
In [30]: b = np.arange(10)
In [31]: b[idx[0]] += 10
In [32]: b
Out[32]: array([10,  1,  2, 13,  4,  5, 16,  7,  8, 19])
```

Here the action is the same (`add.at` is slower).  But if there were duplicates in `idx` the results will be different.

`+=` also works with the boolean mask:

```
In [33]: b[cond] -= 10
In [34]: b
Out[34]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

There's got to be a `ufunc` equivalent to the `+=` operator, but I don't use `ufunc` enough to know off hand.